# Wordpress Update User Function Timeout

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm currently trying to create a PHP script for a Wordpress site that updates all  User Accounts'(5000+) first name, last name, and zipcode. The updated data is being pulled from a separate query made by a form that all users filled out during registration. My issue isn't actually updating the users, I am able to do this without issue. The problem is updating all of the 5000+ users before the HTTP request times out. After a minute or two I am sent to a page that reads "HTTP Error 504 - Gateway Timeout". Some of the User data has been updated but I would like that to be the case for all of them.

I am running a for loop to complete this task. Below is the portion of the code that is running the update.

```
   for ($x = 0; $x <= $total_registers; $x++) {
        $first_name = $registers[$x]["2.3"];
        $last_name = $registers[$x]["2.6"];
        $profile_zipcode = $registers[$x]["18"]
        $main_id = $registers[$x]["created_by"];

        $user_update = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $main_id, 'first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name, $profile_zipcode => 'profile_zipcode' ) );

    }
```

Would anybody know how to accomplish this without the timeout error?

Thanks!

Comment: `$profile_zipcode => 'profile_zipcode'` should it not be  `'profile_zipcode'=>$profile_zipcode` ?

Comment: Ahh yes you are correct! But unfortunately that does not fix my initial issue. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Just before the loop, this value will override the set_time_limit value.

Hope it can help you !